# Calling actionCreator function is not working through bindActionCreators

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am attaching dispath with actionCreator like bellow

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({},basicActions), dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewClientSetup);
```

and calling actionCreator function like this

```
componentCallback:text => actions(basicActions.selectOption(text))
```

this is basicActions.js

```
export function selectOption(text){
    debugger;
    const actionObj = {
        type: types.SELECT_OPTION,
        id: nextActionId++,
        text
    };
    return actionObj;
}


export function requestSuccess(){
    console.log('inside requestSuccess');
    return {type:'SUCCESS',id:1}
}

export function fetchS1Users(parentUserId){
debugger;
    axios.get(url, {
        params: {
          parentUserVal: parentUserId
        },
        responseType: 'json'
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('res '+response.data);
        console.log('res JSON '+JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

    return {
        id: nextActionId++,
        type: types.FETCH_USERS,
        inputParam: parentUserId,
        s1users:{}
    }
}
```

but its giving error 'Uncaught TypeError: actions is not a function'

this is working though

```
 actions: bindActionCreators(basicActions.selectOptions, dispatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have used `bindActionCreators` to bind the actions, you could use them from props and not call the actions as function like

`this.props.actions.selectOption()`

Comment: thanx, but it didn't  work this way for me.
now I am calling like this and its working
 `this.props.actions(basicActions.selectOptions('abc'))`